# Visual Basic .Net is changing my variables for me, and throwing errors in my program

Tags: .net, visual-studio, variables, visual-studio-2008, tetris

I am a Grade 11 IPT (programming) student from Australia. I have an assignment in which I need to make an old-style game. I chose to make tetris and am almost finished, but have a few issues.

I am having issues with Visual Basic .Net (2008). The program is changing a variable without being programmed to do so. It is in a module and the Sub is the only place where the variable exists.

Basically, the variable (called intLineFilled) holds the number of squares there are in a certain horizontal line within the playing field. I then have an IF statement to test whether it becomes equal to the total number of squares that would fit in a line. (The width of the game panel divided by the width of the squares.) When this occurs, it is meant to change a Boolean value to true to signify that there is a line.

My issue is this:
When debugging, after the first block has been placed (sometimes second or third, depending on luck), when it reaches the aforementioned IF statement, the value is only 1, 2 or 3, depending on the block type. But the IF statement still runs, and testing for the value of variable intLineFilled during or after the IF statement tells me that its value is 16 (which is the value it needs to reach for a line). From this, I am getting an error wherein the program has told me that there are 5 lines on the form, which throws an error with an array I use later. The code worked fine to begin with, but now it doesn’t.

```
    Dim intLineChecker_Left As Integer = frmGame.picGamePanel.Left
    Dim intLineChecker_Top As Integer = frmGame.picGamePanel.Top + frmGame.picGamePanel.Height - intSquareSize

    Dim blnLine As Boolean = False
    Dim intLineFilled As Integer = 0
    Dim intLineNum As Integer = 0
    Dim intLine(4) As Integer
    For index As Byte = 0 To 4
        intLine(index) = 0
    Next index

    While intLineChecker_Top > frmGame.picGamePanel.Top
        While intLineChecker_Left < (frmGame.picGamePanel.Left + frmGame.picGamePanel.Width)
            For Each placedblock In frmGame.Controls
                If placedblock.Tag = "placed" Then
                    If placedblock.Left = intLineChecker_Left Then
                        If placedblock.Top = intLineChecker_Top Then
                            intLineFilled += 1
                        End If

                    End If
                End If
            Next placedblock
            If intLineFilled = frmGame.picGamePanel.Width / intSquareSize Then
                blnLine = True
            End If
            If blnLine = True Then
                intLineNum += 1
                frmGame.TextBox1.Text = frmGame.TextBox1.Text + "bln: " + Str(intLineNum) + ", "
                intLine(intLineNum) = intLineChecker_Top
            End If
            intLineChecker_Left = intLineChecker_Left + intSquareSize
        End While
        blnLine = False
        intLineFilled = 0
        intLineChecker_Left = frmGame.picGamePanel.Left
        intLineChecker_Top = intLineChecker_Top - intSquareSize
    End While
```

My project is in a zip file at the following link if anyone wants to take a look:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/99btww63qpl0pjm/Tetris.zip

The game needs to be finished by tomorrow but I can't proceed with anything else until I sort this out.

Comment: Sorry, but nobody can answer your question without seeing your code, and nobody will download a random zip file. Update your answer and remove this wall of text and add the parts of your code where the error occurs

Comment: Everything works after the above code, but I need to figure out why I have this issue before I can make any more adjustments to my program.

Comment: I guarantee you that it's not "changing your variables". What is the exact problem? What variables are not set to the values you're expecting?

Comment: intLineFilled is the number of squares in the line that it is testing. If this reaches (frmGame.picGamePanel.Width/intSquareSize), which happens to be 16, then blnLine becomes equal to true, and the number of lines (intLineNum) increases. I asked it to display the value of intLineFilled before the IF statement: "If intLineFilled = frmGame.picGamePanel.Width / intSquareSize Then", and not once in the text does it say that intLineFilled reached 16. If I do the same test after the IF statement, then it tells me that it equals 16.

Comment: This is occurring as early as the second block that I place, and it ends up saying that I have 5 lines, which throws an error when intLine(intLineNum) is referred to because intLineNum=5, and the array intLine() only goes to 4

Comment: Here's something to consider: You're doing division. What happens to remainders when you're storing the result of division in an `int`, which only holds whole numbers?

Comment: I strongly suggest you [learn how to use a debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Also, any time you have “throwing errors in my program” it's pretty important to **show us the error**.

Comment: The answer to the division sum is a whole number anyway

Comment: And I am using the debugger, which makes it all the more confusing that it increases the value when it shouldn't

Comment: I have said what the error is: intLineNum is increasing to 16 at the IF statement, where it tests if intLineNum equals 16, not before.